# Getting correct status message of a shell script when using variables in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a `shell` script like below.

```
#!/bin/bash

source /home/$USER/source.sh

[ $# -ne 1 ] && { echo "Usage : $0  table "; exit 1; }

table=$1

TIMESTAMP=`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`
touch /home/$USER/logs/${TIMESTAMP}.success_log
touch /home/$USER/logs/${TIMESTAMP}.fail_log
success_logs=/home/$USER/logs/${TIMESTAMP}.success_log
failed_logs=/home/$USER/logs/${TIMESTAMP}.fail_log
touch /home/$USER/logs/${TIMESTAMP}.log
logs=/home/$USER/logs/${TIMESTAMP}.log

function log_status
{
       status=$1
       message=$2
       if [ "$status" -ne 0 ]; then
                echo "`date +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\"` [ERROR] $message [Status] $status : failed" | tee -a "${failed_logs}"
                echo "$output" | tee -a "${logs}"
       else
                    echo "`date +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\"` [INFO] $message [Status] $status : success" | tee -a "${success_logs}"
                    echo "$output" | tee -a "${logs}"
       fi
}

Final=$(spark-submit --name "Spark" --master "yarn-client" /home/$USER/import.py $table)

output=$(echo "$Final" | tail -1)
echo "$output"

g_STATUS=$?
log_status $g_STATUS  "spark $table"

#output=$(echo "$Final" | tail -1)
echo "$Final"
#echo "$output"
echo "****************************************************************************************************************************"
```

In this the variable `output` has to be appended to file.

Now when I have like below in the script.

```
output=$(echo "$Final" | tail -1)
echo "$output"
echo "$Final"

g_STATUS=$?
log_status $g_STATUS  "spark $table"
```

I am getting the `output` variable printed in the `logs` file which is my expected result. But the status of the `shell script` is always success, even if `Final =$(spark-submit --name "Spark" --master "yarn-client" /home/$USER/import.py $table)` fails

Now when I have like below in the script.

```
g_STATUS=$?
log_status $g_STATUS  "spark $table"

output=$(echo "$Final" | tail -1)
echo "$output"
echo "$Final"
```

Then the status of the `shell script` is always success, if `Final =$(spark-submit --name "Spark" --master "yarn-client" /home/$USER/import.py $table)` is success and the status of the `shell script` is always failed, if `Final =$(spark-submit --name "Spark" --master "yarn-client" /home/$USER/import.py $table)` is failed

And I am not having `output` variable printed in the `logs` file.

What should I do in order to have the `output` variable printed all the time to the `logs` file and have the correct status message.

I mean if the status of `Final =$(spark-submit --name "Spark" --master "yarn-client" /home/$USER/import.py $table)` is success then `shell` script status to be success if not then failed.

Comment: In the future, please try to ask questions around code with a [mcve] -- with the smallest amount of code necessary to reproduce the issue, with content not strictly needed for that purpose removed.

Comment: BTW, http://shellcheck.net/ will identify a number of issues with this code without the need to get humans involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried saving the status right after you execute the subshell of interest, and then returning it at the very end?

```
Final =$(spark-submit --name "Spark" --master "yarn-client" /home/$USER/import.py $table)
g_STATUS=$?
output=$(echo "$Final" | tail -1)
echo "$output"


log_status $g_STATUS  "spark $table"


echo "$Final"

echo "****************************************************************************************************************************"
return $g_STATUS
```

Comment: Surely you don't want the space before the `=` (which causes the script to invoke a command named `Final`, rather than assign to a variable by that name).

Comment: Good point. Viru reddy, when you have confirmed that the error status propogates everywhere you want it to propogate, removing the space before the equals signs will fix the variable assignment. :)

Comment: @BjarturThorlacius The solution works but I am getting `return: can only `return' from a function or sourced script` after the script execution

Comment: @Virureddy, in that case you need `exit` rather than `return`.

Comment: To clarify the original problem: `$?` is the exit status of the *last command* executed; in the original code, the last command was `echo`, so you were getting the status from that.